# MVC Rhino Mocks for Request.Files

Tags: unit-testing, model-view-controller, mocking, rhino-mocks

I'm trying to get my controller in a unit test to return a mock file when `Request.Files[0]` is called

From other posts on this site I've put together:

```
[TestMethod]
        public void CreateFileInDatabase()
        {
            var repository = new MocRepository();
            var controller = GetController(repository);

            HttpContextBase mockHttpContext = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpContextBase>();
            HttpRequestBase mockRequest = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpRequestBase>();
            mockHttpContext.Stub(x => x.Request).Return(mockRequest);

            mockRequest.Stub(x => x.HttpMethod).Return("GET");

            var filesMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpFileCollectionBase>();
            var fileMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpPostedFileBase>();
            filesMock.Stub(x => x.Count).Return(1);
            mockRequest.Stub(x => x.Files).Return(filesMock);
            var t = mockHttpContext.Request;

            var automobile = new Automobile{ automobileNumber = "1234" };
            controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(mockHttpContext, new RouteData(), controller);
            controller.Create(automobile);
        }
```

When I'm in the controller during a test and call `Request.Files` I get the filesMock great.

However I want to be able to call `Request.Files[0]` and get a mock File which I can pass as a parameter to a method.

I haven't done much mocking before so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filesMock object is a mock, therefore it have no idea how to resolve Files[0]. You need to tell it what to return, if someone asks for the first file:

```
filesMock.Stub(x => x[0]).Return(fileMock);
```

Add the above line after the creation of the fileMock object and the code works :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add an abstraction over the `Request.Files[0]` via an interface and object that actually calls out to `Request.Files[0]`

Note: I'm not actually sure what the datatype is for `Request.Files[0]`, just using `IFile` as an example.

```
public interface IFileRetriever
{
    IFile GetFile();
}

public class FileRetriever
{
    public IFile GetFile()
    {
        return Request.Files[0];
    }
}
```

Obviously suit the interface and real implementation to your use case, it will probably not be what is above...

In your class that currently calls out to `Request.Files[0]` just take in the IFileRetriever as a dependency, which is straightforward to mock out in Rhino Mocks (or any mocking/faking framework)